# SHA1 SHA256 command

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

So I created an android app from the
while running the "keytool" command from the "Authenticating your client" site for firebase on the project folder, I get this error

```
keytool -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of text. Copy the text into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that I've made 2 mistakes :
1- Windows don't support two lines command so the command must be typed :
"keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\debug.keystore"
2- Windows don't genere the user profile (%USERPROFILE%) automatically like MacOS or Linux so you should search the next path : C:\users\YourUserName.android
[Run the command and get the password that must be "android" and you get your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMnqY.png)

Answer (score 1):

Write the whole command on one line:

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

Windows does not support to split a command line with `\`.

Comment: keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:910)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:416)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:409)

Comment: Change the path to where your keystore file actually resides.